# Why variable name as underscore character ("_") not working for Deconstruction

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-core-3.1

I have declared a variable as underscore character `_` like below and the compiler able to execute the code smoothly.

```cs
 int _ = 10;
 _ += 10;

 onsole.WriteLine(_);
```

But, the compiler is not detecting the variable named as underscore character `_` for a [Deconstruction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/deconstruct) syntax shown below.

```cs
(string _, int age) = new Student("Vimal", "Heaven", 20);
```

At the same time, compiler and Visual Studio intellisense detect the variable named as underscore `_` for another syntax shown below.

```cs
var student  = new Student("Vimal", "Heaven", 20);
(string _, int age) details = student.GetDetails();

Console.WriteLine(details._);
```

I understand that nobody use underscore character to name a variable. Why compiler is inconsistent in handling the underscore `_` character?

I am not discussing about the C# `discards` here.

The `Student` class referred in the sample.

```cs
public class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public Student(string name, string address, int age = 0) => (Name, Address, Age) = (name, address, age);

    public void Deconstruct(out string name, out int age) => (name, age) = (Name, Age);
    public (string, int) GetDetails() => (Name, Age);
}
```

Comment: Is it treating it as a [discard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/discards)?

Comment: No, I am not discussing about the discard feature here but the way _ variable is treated in the deconstruction

Comment: But the compiler is treating it as a "discard", so use a regular name for it

Comment: Make an experiment. Introduce two underscore variables `(string _, int _)`. If you get a compiler error then your compiler doesn't know about discards. But if compiler does not report an error then it does in fact know about discards.

Comment: It's definitely a discard: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/discards - the very first example in that link demonstrates a tuple deconstruction discard.

Comment: If you're using a `_` in a position where the compiler implements discards, then whether or not *you* intended it to be treated as a discard is irrelevant.

Comment: @MatthewWatson discard syntax can be considered as  var(_, int age) which discards the first variable. But i am declaring (string _, int age) two variables with type. We don't need to specify a type for a discards variable

Comment: Discards don't *need* a type, true, but you seem to be refusing to consider whether they *allow* a type to be specified. Point 2 from these [language design meeting notes](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/98043cdc889303d956d540d7ab3bc4f5044a9d3b/meetings/2016/LDM-2016-11-15.md) would indicate that they do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why compiler is inconsistent in handling the underscore _ character?

In each of the first three code snippets, the `_` character is interpreted a different way.

Here:

```
(string _, int age) details = student.GetDetails();
```

`(string _, int age)` is syntactically the *type* of the variable `details`, and the variable name is `details`, not `_`. `_` is part of the type name, specifically the [tuple field name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples#tuple-field-names).

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/discards) (emphasis mine):

> You indicate that a ***variable*** is a discard by assigning it the underscore (_) as its name.

So the `_` in `(string _, int age) details` is not a discard. This is why you can access it as `details._`.

Later in the same page:

> In C# 7.0, discards are supported in assignments in the following
> contexts:
>
> - Tuple and object deconstruction.
> - Pattern matching with is and switch.
> - Calls to methods with out parameters.
> - A standalone _ when no _ is in scope.

The situation you have here:

```
int _ = 10; 
_ += 10;

Console.WriteLine(_);
```

is not on the list, so discards do not apply there. In the first line, It is not "A standalone `_`", so `_` is not a discard, and you declared a variable called `_`. In the following lines, there is a `_` in scope, because you declared a variable with that name on the first line.

The second code snippet you showed:

```
(string _, int age) = new Student("Vimal", "Heaven", 20);
```

is a "Tuple and object deconstruction", which is on the list, so this time `_` is treated as a discard, and this time it doesn't declare a variable called `_`.

Comment: discards operation doesn't need to specify a datatype eg: var(_, _, int age) where first two are discarded. But I have declared as (string _, int age) that means a variable name as _ with type string

Comment: @VimalCK Wrong. In `(string _, int age) details`, `details` is the variable name, `(string _, int age)` is the variable's type. I know it doesn't look like one, but it is.

Comment: Also, `(string _, int age) details = student.GetDetails();` is not a deconstruction. The left hand side and right hand side are of the same types.

Comment: @VimalCK is correct. `details._` is valid. `(_, int age)` would be a discard. [Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AXLCqU).

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay I didn't say `details._` isn't valid. The whole reason why it is valid is that the `_` in `(string _, int age) details` is not a discard! It's not a variable name either. It's a [tuple field name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples#tuple-field-names). The `_` in `var (_, int age)` _is_ a discard, because it's doing deconstruction. But `var (_, int age)` is not mentioned in the question, and I don't understand OP's point of mentioning it here, so I did not respond to it.